# How to determine if a certificate is being used

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate

I inherited an environment that's a mess with zero documentation on which programs are using which certificates that are installed.  It's an old server - Windows server 2008 - and I'm working on updating the environment.  Part of that updating is determining which certificates I still need.  I've used certutil to check which certs were expired/revoked.  The issue I'm running into now is how can I check which of the remaining certificates are actually being used?  The only "solution" I can think of is to move/delete a certificate and see what no longer works and I'm not sure that's going to get by the change review board at work.  Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your specific environment:

It's probably fastest and cheapest to run a scream test. The change review board may not like the suggestion, but sometimes things like the scream test are the only reasonable things left. Just establish a solid back out plan.

You can hunt and prod and monitor and still miss edge cases from things that happen only twice a year or other weird constraints.